# Fit 3D curve to surface

Tags: python, optimization, 3d, computational-geometry, curve

I have the 3D coordinates of curves that look e.g. like this: [image: example curve] and I have a point cloud of a sphere-like 3D surface.
Is it possible, to determine a starting point A at this surface and a starting vector and then align this curve so that all points have on average the closest distance to this surface, it starts at A and its beginning is parallel to the starting vector?
Kinda like this:
[image]

I couldn't find any libraries online.

Comment: Do you need the curve to start exactly on the surface ? Do you need the starting direction to be exactly in the tangent plane ? Do you need the end point to also lie exactly on the surface ?

Comment: no, it is just for the alignment, it does not have to be perfect

Answer (score 0):

**Hints:**

Such problems can be addressed by the method of least-squares. You have four unknowns which are the coordinates of the center and the radius, and you can minimize a quantity like

```
Σ((Xi - Xc)² + (Yi - Yc)² + (Zi - Zc)² - R²)². *
```

You can add constraints such as expressing that the sphere passes by a known point

```
(Xp - Xc)² + (Yp - Yc)² + (Zp - Zc)² = R² **
```

or that the normal at a known point is orthogonal to a given direction

```
(Xp - Xc).Dx + (Yp - Yc).Dy + (Zp - Zc).Dz = 0 ***
```

and recast the problem using Lagrangian multipliers.

In all cases, this leads to a system of polynomial equations.

---

*A more robust expression such as

```
Σ|√((Xi - Xc)² + (Yi - Yc)² + (Zi - Zc)²) - R|
```

can be used but is more challenging to handle numerically.

**This can be used to eliminate `R²`. It reduces the problem to a quadratic minimization that has an analytical solution.

***This can be used to eliminate `Zc`, as an affine function of `Xc`, `Yc`, making the analytical solution yet simpler.